# How do I render multiple partials based off of JSON data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have a database with user data, If I wanted to render a partial for each document in my MongoDB collection how would I do that?

I can render one partial by just adding it to my view but how do I make it render multiple ones automatically without me retyping this {{>somePartial}} for each new document added?

I looked around and found something suggesting AJAX they were not completely similar to my problem. If this is the solution is there another way other then AJAX?

every time a new document is added to MongoDB I'd like a new partial added to my view (I don't mind if it only shows when the page is refreshed)

```
{{>somePartial}} // Different data
{{>somePartial}} // Different data
{{>somePartial}} // Different data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of all the data from your `monogdb` then you can render your page and pass your data to the `ejs` template and add dynamic includes and pass different data e.g.

```
<% for (let i = 1; i <= <length>; i++) { %>
    <%- include("<partial>",{data:"your_data_for_this_index"}) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Brilliant I would have never thought of doing that. Thank you so much!